# Swift package manager make Package depend on remote XCFramework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, swift-package-manager

I need to break app into modules distributed trough SPM. Each module can have some dependencies like FBSdk, Firebase and so on. To reduce build time I need to make my packages depend on binary versions of these SDKs rather than source.

Here is an example of my current package:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Analytics",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Analytics",
            targets: ["Analytics"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(name: "AppsFlyerLib", url: "https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/AppsFlyerFramework.git", from: "6.3.4"),
        .package(name: "Amplitude", url: "https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-iOS.git", from: "8.3.0"),
        .package(name: "Firebase", url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", from: "8.0.0"),
        .package(name: "Facebook", url: "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git", from: "9.3.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "Analytics",
            dependencies: [
                "AppsFlyerLib",
                "Amplitude",
                .product(name: "FirebaseAnalytics", package: "Firebase"),
                .product(name: "FacebookCore", package: "Facebook"),
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

As you can see it depends from source version of FBSdk but it is also distributed as XCFramefork as you can see in [releases section](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/releases)

So my question: is it possible to define dependency from released XCFramework rather than whole repo?

Something like that:

```
 dependencies: [
        // Other dependencies goes here
        .package(name: "Facebook", url: "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/releases/download/v11.1.0/FacebookSDK.xcframework.zip", from: "11.1.0"),
    ],
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but the syntax is wrong. It's not a `.package`, it's a `.binaryTarget`. Here's an example of a Package.swift from the team behind the Swift library `WalletCore`, who did exactly this because they had dependencies on C libraries that were not easy to distribute.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "WalletCore",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "WalletCore", targets: ["WalletCore", "SwiftProtobuf"]
        )
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "WalletCore",
            url: "https://github.com/hewigovens/wallet-core-spm/releases/download/0.0.1/WalletCore.xcframework.zip",
            checksum: "c524cfcd8a6a811f40fb7f5dadfd671944da0c70d78befbec43f4b81a7b7cd47"
        ),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "SwiftProtobuf",
            url: "https://github.com/hewigovens/wallet-core-spm/releases/download/0.0.1/SwiftProtobuf.xcframework.zip",
            checksum: "270a6545f72a512aafc7d7ecb73621005248d4ea44f7ebbc06a2f33c7d15bc4c"
        )
    ]
)
```

**Note:**
There are some build issues in some circumstances when doing this. Not clear what the exact issue is. The WalletCore library worked fine for me, but another library doing the same thing, "Sodium", causes intermittent build issues being unable to find the .xcframework sometimes. There is an open rdar on it and it seems to be called out as a "known issue" on Xcode 13 betas. So fingers crossed it will be fixed with 13.

Comment: You definitely right but the question is more related to Facebook SDK itself rather than general binary targets

Comment: @SergeyPekar I don't understand this response. You've asked if its possible to do this type of thing, i've said yes it is and given you an example of how I do that exact thing with another library. Whats the uniqueness of facebook in this context?