# Importing Compiled Objective-C Framework Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create Swift Package. This package uses a third-party compiled Objective-C framework to be integrated. Usually, when we integrate such a framework, we add it in Linked Frameworks and import it via bridging header.

But since it is a swift package, I cannot have a bridging header. I also tried to use the umbrella header but it is not working.

Below is my package.swift -

```
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MySPM",
        dependencies: ["ObjCFramework"]),
    .binaryTarget(name: "ObjCFramework",
                  path: "Frameworks/ObjCFramework.xcframework")
]
```

And I tried to create an umbrella header as below -

```
module ObjCFrameworkModule {
    header "Frameworks/ObjCFramework.xcframework/Headers/"
    export *
}
```

I would really appreciate it if I can get some pointers for using the Objective-C framework inside SPM.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Objective C framework in its own Swift Package. Here's an [example](https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement).

Or access the xcframework remotely like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68665383/556617.